# How to spoof browser user-agent in Microsoft Edge?

Tags: browser, microsoft-edge, user-agent

Specifically, how to spoof it consistently for a particular site - I know that it is possible for a single page using the F12 Developer Tools as long as the developer tools pane remains open.

But that's a clunky workaround when there are entire sites (looking at you, inbox.google.com) which actually work perfectly in Edge, but which pretend they don't.

Any settings, extensions, Tampermonkey scripts, etc., that will do this currently?

Comment: You spoof it exactly how you would spoof it with IE11, with the developer tools, the same options are indeed there.  If you need more then that, you would need to write an add-on, or find one that's already written.

Answer (score 0):

Further to @Ramhound's comment you can change the UserAgent string in Egde by opening the developer tools by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>, click on the Emulation tab and on the right there is a dropdown in which you can select the browser you wish to emulated.

[image: Screenshot of UserAgent strings]

Comment: Yeah, I know that; I mentioned it in my opening paragraph. Problem is, it doesn't _stick_ , and it consumes a lot of screen real-estate. I'm looking for an alternate solution.

Comment: You could detach the developer tools window, that way you regain the required real estate.